# Issue with ftCurrency fields with ADODatasets

Tags: delphi, ado, reportbuilder

I have an accuracy problem with a reporting tool that I'm using. The issue is that it is reading in data from a TADODataset on the fly but converting the ftBCD fields into doubles.

This causes rounding errors when performing operations at the reporting level (sums, etc).

I'd like to specify my currency fields as ftCurrency, not ftBCD to stop this from hapening.

If I create a field as:

```
TFieldDef.Create( ADODataset.FieldDefs,
    'test',
    ftCurrency,
    0,
    True,
    0
  );   

ADODataset.CreateDataSet;
```

Using the watch, I can now see that `ADODataset.Fields[0].DataType` has a value of ftBCD.

Is there a way to explicitly specify a ftCurrency field within a TADODataset so it's not assigned as a ftBCD field?

Comment: If it is converting ftBCD fields to double on the fly, it may also do that with ftCurrency fields. In a sense ftCurrency fields are a sort of "poor man's" ftBCD field. ftCurrency fields are set (in stone almost) to maintain accuracy to 4 decimals, meaning that 42.0000 will remain as such and not be "wrecked" to 41.999999999999. ftBCD fields on the other hand have the same ability, but the number of decimals to which they maintain accuracy can be set on a per field basis and can be much larger than 4. OTOH it may be able to deal with currency fields while lacking ftBCD support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ADODataSet.FieldByName('AField').Currency := True;
```

Comment: Thanks. Although you need to typecast is as:

TCurrencyField(ADODataSet.Fielddefs[i]).Currency := True;

Comment: While this sets the field in the dataset to be a currency it is still not passing though to the reporting engine pipeline. I'll have to investigate further.

Comment: i forgot about that, i'm a little bit on hurry. glad that worked. 

best regards,